# Comparison of Windows Debuggers

Tags: debugging, ollydbg, x64dbg, windbg, immunity-debugger

I have some experience reverse engineering ELF files using tools like GDB, radare2, and Ghidra, but I am new to Windows debugging. There are quite a few different debuggers out there for Windows and family, and I was hoping that someone could give me a comparison of them, explaining the similarities and differences, which ones are outdated / obsolete, which are most popular, which are more well suited to certain tasks, etc.

Specifically, the Windows debuggers I have heard of and am most interested to learn more about are:

- WinDbg
- OllyDbg
- Immunity Debugger
- x32dbg / x64dbg

If there are any other debuggers that I didn't mention above that you feel should be part of the comparison, please feel free to include it in your answer.

Comment: I have only experience with ollydbg and x32dbg/x64dbg. Basically x32dbg is an alternative to ollydbg that is still maintained and x64dbg is the 64-bit version of the same thing (which ollydbg doesn't have). For the tasks I need to perform, they are more than enough. In my opinion ollydbg should no longer be used because it is outdated for almost ten years - except e.g. used in an emulated win95/98.

Comment: Jetbrains wrote their own too for their IDE's when the license prohibited them from using WinDbg (so I understood).   I do not know if they open sourced it.